# matplotlib using text instead of number in y ticks

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I want my y axis' tick is text label rather than number, and my x is a series of datetime object, I want a plot to represent a track of a man's event during a day, that's the scene.

**This is my code :**

```
import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates
import matplotlib as mpl

y_text_dict = ["go to dinner", "visit my mom", "go to park", "work"]

x_str=["2016-06-30 09:11",
"2016-06-30 10:11",
"2016-06-30 12:10",
"2016-06-30 16:57",
"2016-06-30 17:17",
"2016-06-30 17:33",
"2016-06-30 17:33",
"2016-06-30 17:48",
"2016-06-30 17:58",
"2016-06-30 18:27"]
x = [datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") for time in x_str]
y = [0,3,2,1,2,2,1,1,3,2]   #so the event series will be "go to dinner"->"work"->"go to park"->"visit my mom"...
y_text = [y_text_dict[i] for i in y]

zhfont1 = mpl.font_manager.FontProperties(fname='/Library/Fonts/Songti.ttc')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_yticklabels(y_text_dict,fontproperties=zhfont1)
#ax.set_yticks(y_text)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90)
plt.step(x, y, where = 'post')
plt.show()
```

The result of this code above is :

[image]

Apparently this is not what I expect.
Also,
I wonder if there is better way to illustrate such an event tracking ?

---

**update:**
I can use these two lines to make it what I expect:

```
ax.set_yticks(xrange(len(y_text_dict)))
ax.set_yticklabels(y_text_dict)
```

Answer (score 2):

as @Julien Bernu suggest, I can make my example working by add these two lines:

```
ax.set_yticks(xrange(len(y_text_dict)))
ax.set_yticklabels(y_text_dict)
```

and the resulting plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
plt.xticks(tick_loc, tick_names)
```

`tick_loc` sets the locations of your ticks, and `tick_names` what to display.

Comment: by using "ax.set_yticklabels(y_labels_dict,fontproperties=zhfont1)" I can label the y axis, But I cannot make my y value list plot according to the value-label pair.

Comment: btw, calling `ax.set_yticks(tick_loc)` and then `ax.set_yticklabels(tick_names)` will also work.

Comment: You save my day! @Julien Bernu, what a dummy I am, I can hardly paraphrase your suggestion, but now I get what you tell me, Thank you!I should not skip the beginner's tuts of matplotlib, after this task I will learn it step by step.